# NEWBIE #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying running the code bellow.

```
DELIMITER $$ 
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS NormalizeMeasures$$
CREATE PROCEDURE NormalizeMeasures()
BEGIN

    -- Variable for Cursor 1
    DECLARE idSensor INT;

END$$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

But I'm receiving the following message:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE PROCEDURE NormalizeMeasures()
>   BEGIN

```
-- Variable for Curso' at line 2
```

But for strange that this can hear, this code already worked.
My Mysql currently version is 5.5.37

Comment: What MySQL client application are you using?

Comment: Versão do servidor: 5.5.37-cll - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: I mean are you using the `mysql` command line client, something like MySQL Workbench, or a different client application? The `DELIMITER` implementation differs, and it looks like your `$$` delimiter isn't respected even though it was not a syntax error to define it.

Comment: I'm using the phpMyAdmin 4.1.8

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem.

It was in a space after the first DELIMITER $$

I remove ir and it works. Stupid but works.....